# Is there a way to use different pre defined arrays each time in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub I got from the web that will arrange the sheet columns in a predefined way. It works for a single sheet but now I have an application where I need to reorder 4 sheets, each in different order.
This code used an array of column headers to renege the columns (colOrdr). My idea was to define an array for each sheet then "swap" the array each time through the loop. (colOdr1, colOdr, ...) But I get a Type mismatch. I know that I'm assigning the var colOrdr incorrectly but I can't figure out how do do this correctly.

```
Sub ColOrder()

Dim search As Range
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim colOrdr As Variant
Dim sheetOrdr1 As Variant
Dim sheetOrdr2 As Variant
Dim sheetOrdr3 As Variant
Dim indx As Integer

' Define column order for each sheet using their column header names
    sheetOrdr1 = Array("ID", "Fname", "Lname", "Addr1", "Addr2", "City", "State", "Zip")
    sheetOrdr2 = Array("ID", "Hphone", "Cphone", "Fax", "Other")
    sheetOrdr3 = Array("ID", "Sdate", "Edate", "Active", "Rate", "Status", "Cert")

    Dim shCount As Integer
    shCount = 1
    For shCount = 1 To 3

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(shCount).Select ' Select worksheets left to right
        colOrdr = colOrdr & shCount ' Assign the array

        cnt = 1
        For indx = LBound(colOrdr) To UBound(colOrdr) ' I GET A TYPE MISMATCH ON THIS LINE
            Set search = Rows("1:1").Find(colOrdr(indx), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
             If Not search Is Nothing Then
                If search.Column <> cnt Then
                    search.EntireColumn.Cut
                     Columns(cnt).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End If
            cnt = cnt + 1
            End If
        Next indx
     Next shCount

End Sub
'''
```

Comment: Note - what version of Excel are you using? PowerQuery is great at reordering columns.

Comment: I suggest that you use an Array of Arrays, that way you should be able to access using colOrdr(shCount)(indx)

Comment: I'm using Excel for Mac ver 16.29.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer proposed by @rskar points out the issue and a way to solve the problem.  I might suggest something like this:

```
Sub ColOrder()
   Dim search As Range
   Dim cnt As Integer
   Dim colOrdr As Variant
   Dim indx As Integer
   Dim shCount As Integer

   For shCount = 1 To 3
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(shCount).Select ' Select worksheets left to right

       ' Define column order for each sheet using their column header names
       Select Case shCount
          Case 1
             colOrdr = Array("ID", "Fname", "Lname", "Addr1", "Addr2", "City", "State", "Zip")
          Case 2
             colOrdr = Array("ID", "Hphone", "Cphone", "Fax", "Other")
          Case 3
             colOrdr = Array("ID", "Sdate", "Edate", "Active", "Rate", "Status", "Cert")
       End Select

       cnt = 1

       For indx = LBound(colOrdr) To UBound(colOrdr)
           Set search = Rows("1:1").Find(colOrdr(indx), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not search Is Nothing Then
               If search.Column <> cnt Then
                   search.EntireColumn.Cut
                    Columns(cnt).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                   Application.CutCopyMode = False
               End If
           cnt = cnt + 1
           End If
       Next indx
    Next shCount
End Sub
```

The code is a little more compact because the number of variables is reduced.

Comment: That's good, but there should be a `Case Else` to throw an error given a `shCount` that isn't expected, since that `Select Case` block will need to be modified if the hard-coded `3` is ever changed to something else. I would also remove the `.Select` call to activate the sheet, and properly qualify implicit `Worksheet` member calls instead of relying on an `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Thanx Brian, your approach and solution were perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This line does not result in an array:

```
colOrdr = colOrdr & shCount ' Assign the array
```

That's why one gets the type mismatch at `For indx`.

I'm guessing you want to somehow loop through sheetOrdr1 .. sheetOrdr3? If so, try this:

```
colOrdr = Choose(shCount, sheetOrdr1, sheetOrdr2, sheetOrdr3) ' Assign the array
```

Comment: TIL `VBA.Interaction.Choose` is a thing =)